# Vue.js with Pre-render SPA Creates Double Script Tags

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application, prerender

I'm building an SEO friendly website using Vue.js, so I'm using [SPA Pre-render plugin](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin).

When I `npm run build` both Vue.js and the Pre-render SPA plugin both mount a version of script tags into the `<head>` of every page, and therefore they're duplicated.

I've tried the following, in `vue.config.js`:

```
new preRender({
          staticDir: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
          routes: ['/', '/page-1', '/page-2'],
          postProcess(renderedRoute) {

            renderedRoute.html = renderedRoute.html.replace(/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/ig,'');

            return renderedRoute;
          }
        })
```

But this removes any and all script tags completely. So not ideal. I've tried the plugin authors but they say this is the intended way the plugin should work, and again it's not ideal as it causes conflicts with services such as Google Analytics, Hotjar, Sentry, etc.

If anyone has any experience with Vue or the plugin, any ideas?

Comment: What backend do you have?

Comment: I have Node.js with Express and Axios, it's just there to send out emails.

Comment: https://github.com/eddyerburgh/vue-cli-ssr-example
https://github.com/cgygd/vue-cli-ssr

Comment: Hey thanks, I was under the impression the SSR is overly complex?